# R Won't Initialize from Terminal -- R 4.3.3, Linux Mint 21.1

Tags: r, linux, rstudio, linux-mint

I'm having an issue with initializing R and thusly, installing RStudio after updating to 4.3.3 while running Mint 21.1.

Whenever I attempt to run R from the terminal, starting a base R session, the command just clears and nothing happens, as if I were executing a command. When I attempt to uninstall and re-install R via the terminal, I get the issue along the lines of "The repository 'https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu vera-cran40/ Release' does not have a Release file."

Everything worked fine with previous versions, but this seems to be something that's only happened since updating to 4.3.3. To get/trigger this message, I was attempting to run "sudo apt update." Happy to provide more context as needed. Thanks!

I have tried uninstalling r-base and r-base-dev via the terminal before re-installing multiple times.

Comment: Does this help?    https://www.linuxcapable.com/how-to-install-r-lang-on-linux-mint/